# Terminal is showing just blank screen

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu,I have installed 16.04.After installing cordova softwares to my laptop terminal is not showing anything.I have made few changes in .bashrc file to set path for android sdk,ANT,JDK.Please tel me the solution i have stucked with this problem from past 3 days.Thank you

Comment: In case you are assuming your  changes to your `.bashrc` are causing this issue - rename `.bashrc` to `.bashrc_backup` or similar and restart your terminal / start a new terminal. If that helps - debug what in your old `.bashrc` is causing this problem. It then might help to add the content of your `.bashrc` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file). You can probably rename the `.bashrc` file to something else for now to get terminal working again and then add back one change at a time to see what is causing the error.